# Creating links to private S3 files which still requires authentication

Tags: python, file, amazon-s3, boto

I'm having trouble with S3 files. I have some python code using boto that uploads file to S3, and I want to write to a log file links to the files I created for future reference.

I can't seem to find a way to generate a link that works to only people that authenticated. I can create a link using the generate_url method, but then anybody who clicks on that link can access the file. Any other of creating the url, creates a link that doesn't work even if I'm logged in (Get an XML with access denied).

Anybody knows of a way of doing this? Preferably permanent links, but I can do with only temporary links that expires after given time

Thanks,
Ophir

Answer (score 1):

No, there really isn't any way to do this without putting some sort of service between the people clicking on the links and the S3 objects.

The reason is that access to the S3 content is determined by your AWS access_key and secret_key.  There is no way to "login" with these credentials and logging into the AWS web console uses a different set of credentials that are only useful for the console.  It does not authenticate you with the S3 service.